# How to cover up wall after removing a row of tiles to fit exhaust vent

Tags: walls, kitchens, mortar, tiling

I recently installed a new exhaust hood in my kitchen. As the new one is slightly larger than the old one, it was necessary for me to remove a row of tiles and mortar below for it to properly fit. Here is a picture of the exhaust vent from below, showing where the tiles are removed:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to cover this up in a cosmestically nice way that doesn't necessarily have to include tiles. I have the following ideas in mind

1. Removing the remaining mortar and make a new layer such that it is smooth **or**
2. Removing the remaining mortar and use an acrylic plate to cover it up

Do you have any other suggestions that could look nice?

Comment: If you decide to use some type of trim material over that space I would recommend that you look at materials that tend to match up with the adjacent cabinets so as to distract the eye away from that area as opposed to it.

Comment: I'd go for matching or complementary tile. That being said, a simple stainless plate might also be acceptable for trim.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that could work well would be to remove the old tile setting cement and and grout left over by adjacent tile. Then source new tile that are cut to fit and install a row along that are set into new setting cement. Afterwards it could look almost perfect.

You would want to look at the tiles that you removed. Some of them may still be re-usable if they did not get all busted up when removed.

Answer (score 0):

A nice piece of stained and varnished oak molding would look good there, and wood is easy to work with. Alternatively, you could paint wood molding to match existing cabinets or fixtures.